# Azure Table Storage Partitioning for Regularly Distributed Data

Tags: azure, database-design, storage, partitioning

I have been reading how to partition my Azure Table Storage to ensure high performance.  I would like to know if my proposed strategy provides the ability to provide efficient and scalable inserts and simple queries to the data store.

I have 1000 different processes uploading a small packet of data ( ~50 bytes ) to AZT every 30 seconds.  My queries will virtually always be to simply query by process and time.  For example, I want to query for all of process A's logs from 7pm to 9pm on a given date.

My proposed strategy is to create a table for each process ( 1000 tables ) and then partition the rows such that each partition contains 6 hours of data ( 4 new partitions per day, 720 rows per partition ).  Partition key 'NOV82012-0' would contain 720 rows from midnight on November 8 until 6AM.  'NOV82012-1' would contain 6AM-Noon, etc...

This should ensure that I always have fewer than 1000 rows in any partition so that I don't have to worry about continuation tokens.  I can also easily 'filter' by process since the data from each process has its own table.

Is this the ideal strategy for this case?  Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Sandrino’s suggestion to go with a single table for all the processes.

One thing ATS does not do too well is support deletes. With this in mind, I suggest partitioning by time range at the table level. This way you can delete the table once you do not need the data for that time range.

A keying structure could then be

Table Name = Prefix + YYYYMM (Year & Month)
Example Process201211

PKey = Process + DDHHMM (Day of month, hour & minutes)
Example A081834, B122359 etc

RKey = Seconds or Sub-seconds.
If you cannot guarantee uniqueness with sub-seconds, consider appending a GUID

Comment: Thank you.  I like this ability to easily purge my storage of old data based on time like this.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need to worry about continuation tokens if you're using the .NET SDK. By calling [AsTableServiceQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee741713.aspx) on a query, you'll get an object that automatically handles continuation tokens.

Based on what you're saying you want to filter on a few criteria:

- Process
- Date
- Time

I don't really see a need to create 1 table per process. You could partition it with a combined key: Process+Date. An example:

- A_20121108
- A_20121109
- B_20121108

By combining the process name with the date you can stick to a single table, just to make things easier. Now about the rows, it's OK to have more than 1000 items per partition. The advantage of having all rows for a given day in the same partition is that you can easily select a range in that partition based on the row key (this is semi-pseudo code, didn't test it - you might want to improve the rowkeys).

```
from item in context.CreateQuery<XXX>("XXX") 
where item.PartitionKey == "A_20121108" && item.RowKey.CompareTo("20121108120000") >= 0 && item.RowKey.CompareTo("20121108193000") <= 0
select item;
```

Comment: Thanks for the analysis.  If at some point I'm accumulating several hundred million rows per month ( still at ~50 bytes per row), is it not better to have those distributed amongst 10,000 tables rather than a single table?  Or does AZTs partitioning make the number of tables irrelevant?

Comment: Tables offer no particular scaling benefit above and beyond what partitions do. If you expect to have a very large amount of data then you may want to plan for partitioning across multiple storage accounts. The multiple table approach would fit that model more easily. The Scalability Targets post can help you determine if that's something to consider: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/11/02/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx

Comment: As Sandrino says if you use .AsTableServiceQuery() continuation tokens will get dealt with for you, but just to clarify a point in your question, any Azure Table query (that's not just PK=x and RK=Y) can return a continuation token even if there are less than 1000 results

Comment: AsTableServiceQuery() does simplify fetching thousands of entities by hiding the continuation token, but it does so in a sequential manner. So if you end up having to fetch more than 1000 entities, the SDK will always make multiple calls, one continuation token at a time. So keeping your entity count per partitionkey at less than 1000 is not required, but good for performance, without entering the complexities of parallel programming for fetching entities.

Comment: Also, I prefer many tables with fewer entities, but it's not required as Sandrino points out. Still, if you ever retire processes later, you won't have to deal with deleting entities in batch (100 at a time) if you keep them all in the same table; you would simply drop the table for the process in question. So I think having 1000 tables actually makes maintenance easier overall. Just my personal opinion.